# Handling @RequestBody

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, spring-mvc

JavaScript code:

```
function deleteMarks(list){
    $http.post('/api/marks/delete/all',list).then(
    function(response){
      refresh();
    },function(response){
        error(response.data.error)
    }
    );
}
```

Controller code:

```
@PostMapping("/delete/all")
public void deleteMarks(@RequestBody @Validated List<Long> request) {

     marksService.deletemarks(request);

}
```

Service code:

```
public void deletemarks(List<Long> list) {
    for (Long id : list) {
        marksRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

I am getting following error

```
angular.js:12759 POST http://localhost:8080/api/marks/delete/all 400()
```

can some one tell me where I have done the mistake.

Comment: What does the JS `list` variable contain? Check if you are passing correct data which corresponds to `Marks`, as mentioned in your controller.

Comment: This code is actually for deleting multiple marks at one time so list is containing index's of all marks which needs to be deleted. JS is working correct that means data is passed correctly from client side but problem is I am not receiving data in controller.

Comment: Can you post json input you're sending from angular ?

Comment: {0:3 } this is the data which is getting posted it is containg index of the marks here 0 is the index of the list and 3 is the index of the marks which needs to be deleted.

Comment: @PRIYANSHI, so the RequestBody in your `deleteMarks()` in your controller should contain List<Marks> as an argument instead of just `Marks`

Comment: And if it's just the indexes/ids, it has to be a `List<String>` or `List<Integer>`

Comment: @OutOfMind I have added my service code now where should I make relevent changes.

Comment: I posted an answer, please have a look and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing "list of Marks" from your JS. The controller handler should be:

```
@PostMapping("/delete/all")
public void deleteMarks(@RequestBody @Validated List<Marks> request) 
{
    marksService.deleteMarks(request);
}
```

If you are passing just the "ids for the Marks", the handler method should be:

```
@PostMapping("/delete/all")
public void deleteMarks(@RequestBody @Validated List<String> request) 
{
    marksService.deleteMarks(request);
}
```

Also in your service code, if you are using the JpaRepository's `delete` method, it takes a single `Mark` object as an argument, so you would have to run a loop over your list of marks and call `delete` for each of them.

Comment: i have updated my service code please have a look at it now i am getting 500() with > could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Comment: kindly help me with this also

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace in your question?

Comment: i have updated question with full stack trace have  a look at it

Comment: It clearly says: `Table 'intscale.marks_feedbacks' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 0):

400 error code shows bad request. Most probably your request structure doesn't match expected request structure.